# Typescript factory method parameters number unknown

Tags: angularjs, typescript

ok. it's maybe little hard to explain, but maybe i will show example:

```
static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
    const directive = ($compile) => new JqSortDirective($compile);
    directive.$inject = this.$inject;
    return directive;
}
```

As you can see I'm creating factory method for directive. 
This sucks - I want that code to be more generic. 
Basically I want this line:

```
const directive = ($compile) => new JqSortDirective($compile);
```

to be depended on this.$inject ( array of strings) and always create new object of this type.

Comment: You mean something like `const directive = (...args) => new JqSortDirective(...args)`, don't you?

Comment: yes. thnx, only that it had to be "THISTYPE" instead of JqSortDirective ( somwething with apply, bind? )

Comment: What does `THISTYPE` stand for? It should be an instance of the class that `factory` belongs to?

Comment: sory, maybe I'm not to concrete. currently I have soething like this :
const directive = (...args) => { 
            return new (this.bind.apply(this, args))
  }
I want contruct this same class basicaly

Comment: `this` is already class constructor in this context. So it should be `const directive = (...args) => new this(...args)`. It should transpile to `.bind.apply` code you've shown. Usually you don't need `bind` and `apply` in typescript at all (unless you want to kill typing by intention).

Comment: right. only then i cant pass array as parameters. right?

Comment: You can. Like that `const directive = (...args) => new this(...args)`. This is language feature. Do you have problems with this piece of code?

Comment: well I know that, but in result I will call constructor with array as a parameter, and I want to call it with few parameters instead (like $scope, $http etc. )

Comment: No, it won't. You may check more on spead operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator